# Resizing not happening in Android for web based application

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, frameset

We are developing a web based Internet application that is required to work in the Smartphones (basically iOS and Android platforms)

The CSS and JS that we use does not have a specific feature to handle orientation. 
The problem that we are facing is that, screen resizing is happening properly in iPhone (in all versions), whereas in most of the Android devices, the resizing from Landscape to Portrait is not happening. 
In other words, when we rotate the device from Landscape to Portrait, the automatic adjusting of the screen is not happening.
But, the resizing is proper when we rotate the device from Portrait to Landscape.

The strange behavior we observed is that, when we used plain HTMLs without the Frame, the resizing is proper.
The problem occurs only when we load the HTML using the Frame.

As our code is tightly coupled with frames, we can not remove it. Kindly help us to resolve this issue.

Comment: did you try to add this code after your opening head tag in you HTML? <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'/>

Comment: Already the below given meta tags are added in the html...<META http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE"> 
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="NO-CACHE, NO-STORE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />

Comment: how about setting your frame width to 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the application use the HTML4 tag frame? If so you're in big trouble because it's [not supported in HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp) and you'll have a lot of problems in the - near - future.
You should consider rebuild the application to today's standard. There's no solution besides that, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, the application uses the HTML4 tag frame

Comment: code is tightly coupled with frames, can not remove it now. plz suggest if any other alternates...

Comment: I'm sorry to say it but I think there's no direct solution. Rely in frameset is a big problem these days and you should avoid it in the future.
What you can do is use ajax instead of frames. Just set divs in the place of the frames and load the pages in these target divs.
Another solution would be the use of iframe. It's not the best solution but might work with little adaptation to the existing code.

Comment: Glad to hear. It's more work but it ensures that you won't have much trouble in the future.